# website hostname and docroot

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way in PHP to get the **hostname** and **document root** from the server?  I'd like to do this without storing them as variables in your php code.  I am reluctant to use $_SERVER because I have heard it is not reliable and subject to attack.  How can this be done on a virtual host?  Does a reliable and safe method exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is reliable but `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` isn’t (see [Chris Shiflett’s *SERVER_NAME Versus HTTP_HOST*](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host)). Only if [Apache’s `UseCanonicalName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) is enabled the canonical name is shown.

Comment: I accepted your solution because it sparked a conversation with my host about if I could safely use SERVER_NAME.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
$docroot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
```

[`getenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) lets you access environment variables. You can see all variables that are available by printing [`phpinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). Maybe [`apache_getenv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php) also helps.

Comment: Does that work in windows environments? Good answer though, +1

Comment: To be honest, I don't about windows, but it is not hard just to try it ;)

Comment: I can test it on XAMP tonight.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, you have access to : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php
There's a breakdown here of using realpath() and $_SERVER to get the doc root:
http://www.helicron.net/php/

Also, you could exec('hostname') or something similar to get the hostname.